# how can I fix the location of html5 canvas element in browser screen?

Tags: browser, html5-canvas

If I adjust the screen size of browser, the animation which create by html5 canvas will move to different location in browser, for instance, the original location is at right top corner, after drag the browser screen to small size, the location is at right bottom corner, how can I fix the location of html5 canvas element in browser ?

Comment: Please include the code that produces this problem.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
//Get the canvas &
var c = $('#canv'),    
    container = $(c).parent();

//Run function when browser resizes
$(window).resize( canvasRemake );

function canvasRemake(){ 
    c.attr('width', $(container).width() );
    c.attr('height', $(container).height() );

    //Call a function to redraw other content (texts, images etc)
}
```

NOTE: that will kill your animation, so what about lucking with page, so if the browser get small the user will have to scroll to see the animation...

just a tho*